# Texas holdem flush

Tags: texas-hold-em

If the board is all spades, for example; T♠5♠4♠6♠J♠

Everyone plays this flush
Who wins if only 5 cards can be used
Only one person has a 7 spades
One person has ace high ( dont know if that applies)

Answer (score 0):

The player with 7 of spades wins because he has the best flush

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, someone holding the 7♠ beats anyone not holding a spade in their hand.

Anyone holding 7♠ or higher (and therefore can beat the board) beats anyone who doesn't (and is therefore playing the board).

Anyone with 7♠8♠ has the nuts with a straight flush and cannot be beaten. Next is 7♠3♠ and then 3♠2♠ for smaller straight flushes.

If no one has a straight flush and multiple players have a spade which is 7 or higher, the highest spade wins.

If no-one has a spade 7 or higher, it's a split pot.

Comment: Confused about the downvote - a comment to explain why would be helpful for me to improve my answers in the future if they're not good.

Comment: Upvoted you to balance it out. Good answer here to a bad question

Comment: Thanks, just wish people who downvoted would leave a comment to explain why - it's hard to improve answers otherwise.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I think that some people downvote any answers to this type of question.

Comment: @HerbWolfe you're probably right. I can imagine if people strongly object to questions like this, they probably see any answers as another opportunity to register their displeasure.